# Why can not I call Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I have a problem with Firebase I can not connect to Firebase Get this message "Failed to connect Check your Internet connection and try again" Knowing that my internet power is very strong

Comment: Have you tried connecting it manually on the website (like the error ussually suggests)?

Comment: Yes, I tried to Many times but it did not work

Comment: Have you set the proper permissions for internet access?

Comment: Yes I did; I do not know why I did not call

Comment: You need to show some code, and explain what you are doing.

Comment: I use version 2 of the Android Studio

Comment: Do you require the latest version of Android Studio ?

Comment: Try using the newest Android Studio, there is a tool to interact with Firebase in it.